# Match the end of the string but not newlines?

Tags: java, regex

Is possible, in java, to make a regex for matching the end of the string **but not** the newlines, using the Pattern.DOTALL option and searching for a line with \n?

Examples:

1)

```
aaa\n==test==\naaa\nbbb\naaa
```

2)

```
bbb\naaa==toast==cccdd\nb\nc
```

3)

```
aaa\n==trick==\naaaDDDaaa\nbbb
```

I want to match

```
\naaa\nbbb\naaa
```

and

```
cccdd\nb\nc
```

but, in the third example, i don't want to match text ater DDD.

```
\naaa
```

Comment: Please elaborate you requirement with sample problem lines

Comment: Yes you can match up until a newline, not including the newline.

Comment: It would be better if you can tell us what text from your input you want to match. We can work on the right regex after that.

Comment: I posted an example, it's not clear?

Comment: Posted a new example, i made a mess with the precedent one.

Comment: Probably you want to match text after `2nd ==`. But which logic should prevent matching text after `DDD` in 3rd example?

Comment: A regex like: `(?DDD|EOF)` should work... or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you need is:

```
"(?s)==(?!.*?==)([^(?:DDD)]*)"
```

Here is the full code:

```
String[] sarr = {"aaa\n==test==\naaa\nbbb\naaa", "bbb\naaa==toast==cccdd\nb\nc", 
                 "aaa\n==trick==\naaaDDDaaa\nbbb"};

Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("(?s)==(?!.*?==)([^(?:DDD)]*)");

for (String s : sarr) {
    Matcher m = pt.matcher(s);
    System.out.print("For input: [" + s + "] => ");
    if (m.find())
        System.out.println("Matched: [" + m.group(1) + ']');
    else
        System.out.println("Didn't Match");
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
For input: [aaa\n==test==\naaa\nbbb\naaa] => Matched: [\naaa\nbbb\naaa]
For input: [bbb\naaa==toast==cccdd\nb\nc] => Matched: [cccdd\nb\nc]
For input: [aaa\n==trick==\naaaDDDaaa\nbbb] => Matched: [\naaa]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. For example, `(?-m)}$` will match a close-brace at the very end of a Java source file. The point is to disable the multiline mode. You can disable as I've shown or by setting the appropriate flag on the `Pattern` instance.

UPDATE: I believe that multiline is off by default when you instantiate a `Pattern`, but is on in Eclipse's find by regex.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post the entire problem. I updated the question with a sample of text.

Comment: Please add also the expected match for your example string. I'm still not clear what you want.

Comment: Posted a new example, i made a mess with the precedent one.

Comment: Now it looks like you want to match everything after the last "=" till the end of input sequence, but I wouldn't bet that's what you **really** want.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I forgot the last example, that shows why I can't just match everything after the last =. I'm really sorry for the time you wasted for me :(